# Binding between UserControl and MainWindow issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command, viewmodel

I'm missing something in this binding because it doesn't work. This is for learning purposes, if you see how this can be improved please tell me. But besides that I'm also interested in know why this is not working.

In my `MainWindow` there is a `CheckBox` with a command bound to it: `checkCommand`.

In **RootViewModel.cs**:

```
 public Command checkCommand { get; set; }


 public RootViewModel()
        {
 checkCommand = new Command(mark);
        }

private void mark()
        {          
            myThingsCollection[0].marked= true;               
        }
```

This command is working properly, and it also changes the state of `marked` to `true` (I've tested this with a `MessageShowBox`).

I've previously added the UC to a `ObsevableCollection<UC>` (`myThingsCollection`) and bound it to a `ItemsControl` this way in **MainWindow.cs**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myThingsCollection}">
                        <DataTemplate> <!--I've ommited some parts here--!>
                           <local:UC/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

The UC is displayed correctly.

`marked` is a property of the `UCViewModel`:

```
class UCViewModel
    {
        #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged


        private bool _marked;
        public bool marked
        {
            get
            {
                return _marked;
            }
            set
            {
                _marked= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("marked");

            }
        }
    }
```

That `UserControl` (`UC`) has a `CheckBox` that I bind this way:

```
 <CheckBox Content="Hello!" IsChecked="{Binding marked}"/>
```

And set the `DataContext` this way (in the code behind **UC.cs.xaml**)

```
        public UC()
    {
        UCViewModel context = new UCViewModel();
        DataContext = context;

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know what it's missing. By the way I'm pretty sure that this is not a good approach to this problem, is there an easier way? Thanks

Comment: -.- *[...] But it doesn't work. [...]* - Very useful, it's like "my application is crashing". Come on, you have to deliver more details. Are you getting any `BindingExpression` errors in your debug output window in VS? Btw, `Command` is this a custom class?

Comment: Yes, Command is a custom class enabling the Commands. I'm not able to see the BindingExpression errors. I'll check again.

Comment: I've set the DataBinding Trace to "All" in Settings, Output Window. But I can't find where that errors are displayed. Are they shown in the same place as the normal errors? If so, there isn't any error.

Comment: No they are not, if you mean the normal error output window, where the compilation errors are shown. Debug > Windows > Output

Answer (score 0):

Download Link: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvryhugwyquqms9/MvvmLight12.rar)

^^ Link should have a project with everything you were doing working fine.

If your looking for suggestions to improve from your code, some pointers:

- Name your variables with a particular Style Guide. Properties start with "Uppercase". [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) can help identifying problems. Yes Style guides are very important :)
- With MVVM, Your `MyThingsCollection` should not be a collection of `UserControl` but they should be a collection of their VM's
- Don't create VM's in code-behind of the View(Unless your sure about what your doing). Not only will that reset your VM but also do it every so often the View gets created which might not be desirable especially in MVVM.
- Use a MVVM helper library when starting with MVVM even if you want to do things yourself. Learn the system and then do it yourself than take the long road right off the bat.
- Do not hold View related elements in the VM. That's breaking MVVM. Just don't do it. There are **tons** of ways to avoid needing to do this even if you think there just aint an alternative. Just search for em

Comment: I've written it incorrectly here, actually it's a collection of VM's. Thanks for the advices. When I create a proyect in MVVM Light there is a bunch of stuff that I (think) don't need and that disturbs me.

Comment: @Sturm well if you don't need something get rid of it. Or create a standard WPF app and add the MVVMLight dll's as references and build it up from there. Things like `ViewModelBase`, `ObservableObject`, `RelayCommand`, `SimpleIOC` are stuff well worth using without modifying while starting up IMO

Comment: "I (think) don't need and that disturbs me" - How can something that you do not understand(you said so yourself) disturb you? They should be things you want to instantly look into and see wht they do and if you reckon they're pointless you can refactor them out accordingly. Being wary of anything you don't understand aint going to teach you much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your view model implementation then try changing your binding syntax.

```
    IsChecked="{Binding path=marked, Mode=TwoWay}"
```